# "by ruled by another" or "be ruled by another"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if you could help me with this short passage:

> 1. Three years after the revolution of 2011 swept away the military strongman, Hosni Mubarak, Egypt could soon **by** ruled by another.
> 2. Three years after the revolution of 2011 swept away the military strongman, Hosni Mubarak, Egypt could soon **be** ruled by another.

(*be ruled*  vs  *by ruled* )

Number 1 is written on BBC but I think it should not be "by ruled". I think it should be "be ruled". Is there any grammatical or lexical point I am not aware of?

Comment: You're quite right; the first *by* is probably a typo, an error by the typist or transcriptionist.

Answer (score 3):

If you say that #1 is from the BBC, then I can only assume that it's a typing mistake on their website. Or perhaps you typed it wrong.  In any case, you're right, the phrase is *be ruled by*.

Comment: Oops!  Just found it. I'll edit right away.